# Advantages vs disadvantages of vm.overcommit_memory=1 vs vm.overcommit_memory=0

Tags: linux, memory, memory-overcommitment

On Linux, if `vm.overcommit_memory=1`, you can allocate huge memory blocks, but if you use less, these will not affect memory usage.

Lets suppose following code:

```
const size_t size = 128;
void p = malloc(size);
process(p, size); // use up to size bytes
```

vs

```
const size_t HUGE_SIZE = 1ull * 1024ull * 1024ull * 1024ull; // 1 GB
const size_t size = 128;
void p = malloc(HUGE_SIZE);
process(p, size); // use up to size bytes
```

memory usage in both case will be "similar" (OK, may be 4 KB in second case, vs 128 bytes in first case)

- is second approach really takes 4 KB?
- is second approach slower?
- what if I have several 1000's blocks of 1 GB?
  what if I often allocate / deallocate these several 1000's blocks?
- any more disadvantages I can not see?
- I read MacOS support the same, any difference there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is second approach really takes 4 KB?

In both cases it takes physical memory as much as accessed by `process()`, with one page granularity. Difference is process address space allocation.

> is second approach slower?

It may be slower on searching for appropriate region in process address space.

> what if I have several 1000's blocks of 1 GB?

On 32-bit system process address space is limited by 32 bits, so it will fail. On 64-bit you'll have a lot of process address space allocated.

> what if I often allocate / deallocate these several 1000's blocks?

You'll bother glibc allocator.